# Cropping in OpenCV return images rotated 90 degrees

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, medical

I want to crop images according to their right frame. I have about 10000 of hand X-ray images to preprocess, and what I have done so far:

1. Apply Gaussian Blur and Threshold (Binary + Otsu) on the image.
2. Apply dilation to get a single object (in this case a hand).
3. Used `cv2.findContours()` to draw outline along the edges around the hand.
4. Used `cv2.boundingRect()` to find the right frame, and then `cv2.minAreaRect()` and `cv2.boxPoints` to get the right points for the bounding box.
5. Used `cv2.warpPerspective` to adjust image according to height and width.

The code below describes the above:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load image, create mask, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
img_path = "sample_image.png"

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
original = image.copy()
blank = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (33,33), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Merge text into a single contour
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 3)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

for c in cnts:
    # Filter using contour area and aspect ratio (x1 = width, y1 = height)
    x, y, x1, y1 = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if (x1 > 500) and (y1 > 700):
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        width = int(rect[1][0])
        height = int(rect[1][1])
        src_pts = box.astype("float32")
        dst_pts = np.array([[0, height-1], [0, 0],
                            [width-1, 0], [width-1, height-1]], dtype="float32")

        M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)
        warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (width, height))
        plt.imshow(warped)
```

If you have a look at [some of the images in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2uGO.jpg), those are the inputs. When I run these images through the code above, [I get an output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1e2S.jpg). Some of them are cropped nicely (straightened), however, some of them are cropped with 90 degree rotations. Is there a code to counter the 'rotating 90 degrees output' problem?

Here are some images:

Image Inputs: [Four X-ray examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfVcK.jpg)

Image Outputs: [Returns images that are 90 degrees rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpc5H.jpg)

Image Outputs wanted: [Straightened image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSEA1.jpg) (Just used Photoshop to straighten them. Dont want to do this for 10000 images...)

#### UPDATE:

I edited the code according to below-mentioned suggestions. After running the some samples, it now returns images that are now 90 degrees slanted to the right.

- Input images: [image]
- Output images: [image]

I doubt it's because of the quality of the images. Maybe it's got to do with OpenCV's `minAreaRect()`? or `boxPoints`?

#### FINAL UPDATE:

According to @Prashant Maurya, the code was updated with a function added to detect whether the position of the hand is left or right. And then mapping src_pts to right dst_pts. Full code is shown below.

Comment: Make sure that src_points and dst_points have the same ordering

Comment: Do you mean src_point's array and dst_point's array must be in the same order?

So, `src_points` =  `[[   8.  367.][ 891.  -59.][1625. 1460.][ 743. 1886.]]`, while `dst_point` is mentioned above?

Comment: If I see it correctly, your dst ist starting bottom-left and have a clockwise ordering, while src looks strange and I cant tell without seeing the images, whether the ordering is the same.

Comment: When you mention my `src_point` look strange, what do you mean by that? Should I do something with `src_pts = box.astype("float32")`? I used this because to get the four points of the image, then tag it to `src_pts` variable if that makes sense?

The image links are given in the post above next to "image inputs" and "image outputs"

Comment: This might be related to the behavior of the minAreaRect function. Check the order of the corners.

Comment: Thank you, but do you perhaps know how to check the order of the corners? Is there a function I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there are two changes which will correct the output:

- The width and height taken in the code is in the wrong order ie: width: 1470 & height: 1118 just switch the values:
- Map src_pts to right dst_pts the current code is mapping top left
  corner to bottom left therefore the image is being rotated.
- Added function to detect whether image is right tilted or left and rotate and rotate it accordingly

Full code with changes is:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load image, create mask, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
img_path = "xray1.png"

image = cv2.imread(img_path)
cv2.imshow("image original", image)
cv2.waitKey(10000)
original = image.copy()
blank = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (33,33), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Merge text into a single contour
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 3)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

def get_tilt(box):
    tilt = "Left"
    x_list = [coord[0] for coord in box]
    y_list = [coord[1] for coord in box]

    print(x_list)
    print(y_list)

    x_list = sorted(x_list)
    y_list = sorted(y_list)

    print(x_list)
    print(y_list)

    for coord in box:
        if coord[0] == x_list[0]:
            index = y_list.index(coord[1])
            print("Index: ", index)
            if index == 1:
                tilt = "Left"
            else:
                tilt = "Right"

    return tilt


for c in cnts:
    # Filter using contour area and aspect ratio (x1 = width, y1 = height)
    x, y, x1, y1 = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if (x1 > 500) and (y1 > 700):
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        print("rect",rect)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        # print("rect:", box)
        tilt = get_tilt(box)

        src_pts = box.astype("float32")

        if tilt == "Left":
            width = int(rect[1][1])
            height = int(rect[1][0])
            dst_pts = np.array([[0, 0],
                                [width-1, 0], [width-1, height-1], [0, height-1]], dtype="float32")
        else:
            width = int(rect[1][0])
            height = int(rect[1][1])
            dst_pts = np.array([[0, height-1], [0, 0],
                            [width-1, 0], [width-1, height-1]], dtype="float32")

        print("Src pts:", src_pts)
        print("Dst pts:", dst_pts)
        M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)
        warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (width, height))
        print("Showing image ..")
        # plt.imshow(warped)
        cv2.imshow("image crop", warped)
        cv2.waitKey(10000)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your suggestion. 

Unfortunately, after running through some sample after editing the code according to your suggestions, I got some images that are now slanted to the right. I updated the post above.

Comment: Yes the images which are slightly tilted to right will be rotated to right as per the mappings mentioned by me

Comment: I understand. However, I want to straighten all the images upwards? Such that the fingers are pointing upwards instead of slanted to the left or right?

Comment: wait I will update the logic to handle both the cases

Comment: @Bathtub please refer to the updated code

Comment: I looked at your code and tried it out. And thank you so much! It worked like a charm. I see that you created another function to detect whether it's left/right? That's super awesome!

Comment: @PrashantMaurya great approach!